# How to make a label near the corners of a rectangle in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-node

How to make a label near the inner corners of a rectangle in Tikz?
I want to add a letter to each corner of the small rectangle. The letter must still be inside the rectangle.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}    

\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}
      \begin{center}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
       \fill [orange] (-2,-1) rectangle (2,2);
       \draw (-2, -1) rectangle (2,2);
       \fill [white] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
       \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
       \draw[->, thick] (0.5, 0.5) -- (2.3, 1);
       \fill [orange] (2.5,0.5) rectangle (1+2.5,1.5);
       \draw (2.5,0.5) rectangle (1+2.5,1.5);
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \end{center}
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a more versatile way unlike [Miyase's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/267211/miyase) solution that uses absolute coordinates.

You can insert `node` path operator after `rectangle` and by adjusting `anchor` option make nodes inside.

This way nodes do not depend on any absolute coordinates and by changing rectangle dimensions, labels will stay at the right place.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}
      \begin{center}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
       \fill [orange] (-2,-1) rectangle (2,2);
       \draw (-2, -1) rectangle (2,2);
       \fill [white] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
       \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
       \draw[->, thick] (0.5, 0.5) -- (2.3, 1);
       
       \draw[font=\tiny, outer sep=5pt, fill=orange] (2.5,0.5) rectangle node[anchor=north west]{1} node[anchor=north east]{2} node[anchor=south west]{3} node[anchor=south east]{4} (1+2.5,1.5);
       
       \draw (2.5,0.5) rectangle (1+2.5,1.5);
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \end{center}
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Edit:

As [Qrrbrbirlbel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16595/qrrbrbirlbel) pointed out, I was wrong about automatic placement for arbitrary rectangle. The previous solution is still valid as long as you are ok with tweaking around `outer sep` option.

However, in sake of versatility that I was after, here's slightly different approach:

Instead of using `rectangle` path operator, you can use

```
(2.5,0.5) |- (2+2.5,1.5) |- cycle
```

that draw the same rectangle as

```
(2.5,0.5) rectangle (2+2.5,1.5)
```

But the advantage of that approach is that you can now specify `node`s explicitly before and after `|-` operator and the nodes will already placed in corners.

[image]

```
\draw[font=\tiny, fill=orange] (2.5,0.5) node{1} |- node{2} (2+2.5,1.5) node{3} |- node{4} cycle;
```

Now it's only matter of aligning labels so that they will appear inside the rectangle. You can do it via either `anchor` option as in the previous solution or via `left`, `right`, `above`, `below` combination that are equivalent to anchor ones. And the last this is to add `inner sep` to add some padding

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}
      \begin{center}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
       \fill [orange] (-2,-1) rectangle (2,2);
       \draw (-2, -1) rectangle (2,2);
       \fill [white] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
       \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
       \draw[->, thick] (0.5, 0.5) -- (2.3, 1);
       
       \draw[font=\tiny, inner sep=2pt, fill=orange] (2.5,0.5) node[above right]{1} |- node[below right]{2} (2+2.5,1.5) node[below left]{3} |- node[above left]{4} cycle;
       
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \end{center}
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's what I had in mind when I said "There are probably more elegants ways to do it" but I still need to develop better habits with TikZ. Thanks.

Comment: “nodes do not depend on any absolute coordinates and by changing rectangle dimensions, labels will stay at the right place” → No, they will always be placed 5pt away from the center of the rectangle.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel thank you for the remark, I added alternative approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine

```
\fill [orange] (-2, -1) rectangle (2,2);
\draw          (-2, -1) rectangle (2,2);
```

to

```
\filldraw[fill=orange] (-2, -1) rectangle (2,2);
```

which saves you specifying the coordinates twice.

If you want to cut out a rectangle inside a rectangle you can do this with the [`even odd rule`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-actions#pgf./tikz/even:odd:rule) in one path:

```
\filldraw[fill=orange] (-2, -1) rectangle (2,2) (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
```

---

For placing the letters inside the corners, I'll provide you with a custom `to path` named `rectangle mark corners inside`:

```
\tikzset{
  rectangle mark corners inside/.style n args={4}{%
    to path={
      rectangle (\tikztotarget)
      node[anchor=north east, corner label/.try] at (\tikztotarget) {#1}
      node[anchor=north west, corner label/.try] at (\tikztostart|-\tikztotarget) {#2}
      node[anchor=south west, corner label/.try] at (\tikztostart) {#3}
      node[anchor=south east, corner label/.try] at (\tikztostart-|\tikztotarget) {#4}}}}
```

This basically still does `(<start>) rectangle (<target>)` but it uses the coordinates given by you to place the nodes at the corners.

This still allows you to use the `even odd rule` without having to give the coordinates twice:

```
\filldraw [fill=orange, even odd rule]
  (-2, -1)    rectangle                           (2, 2)
   (0,  0) to[rectangle mark corners inside=ABCD] (1, 1);
```

I've added the style `corner label` to the corner nodes so that you can set the style of those nodes in a central place.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  rectangle mark corners inside/.style n args={4}{%
    to path={
      rectangle (\tikztotarget)
      node[anchor=north east, corner label/.try] at (\tikztotarget) {#1}
      node[anchor=north west, corner label/.try] at (\tikztostart|-\tikztotarget) {#2}
      node[anchor=south west, corner label/.try] at (\tikztostart) {#3}
      node[anchor=south east, corner label/.try] at (\tikztostart-|\tikztotarget) {#4}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[corner label/.style={font=\tiny}]
  \filldraw [fill=orange, even odd rule]
    (-2, -1)    rectangle                           (2, 2)
     (0,  0) to[rectangle mark corners inside=ABCD] (1, 1);
  \draw[->, thick] (0.5, 0.5) -- (2.3, 1);
  \filldraw [fill=orange!50]
    (2.5, 0.5) to[rectangle mark corners inside={1}{foo}{bar}{4}] (1+2.5,1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: With  [`\usetikzlibrary{qrr.paths.timer}`](https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf/blob/master/tikzlibraryqrr.paths.timer.code.tex) one can simply do `(2.5, 0.5) rectangle node[at start]{bar} node[near start]{4} node[midway] {1} node[near end] {foo} (1+2.5,1.5)`, i.e. placing the nodes along the path.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably more elegants ways to do it, but simple `\node` commands should do the trick:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}
      \begin{center}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
       \fill [orange] (-2,-1) rectangle (2,2);
       \draw (-2, -1) rectangle (2,2);
       \fill [white] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
       % Position nodes in the corners
       \node at (0,0)[above right]{\small $A$};
       \node at (1,0)[above left]{\small $B$};
       \node at (1,1)[below left]{\small $C$};
       \node at (0,1)[below right]{\small $D$};
       %
       \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
       \draw[->, thick] (0.5, 0.5) -- (2.3, 1);
       \fill [orange] (2.5,0.5) rectangle (1+2.5,1.5);
       \draw (2.5,0.5) rectangle (1+2.5,1.5);
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \end{center}
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]